# Excel if match value then set empty

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to use excel formula to check on Sheet 1 column A value. If the value of column A match to the value of column B in Sheet 2, then the Sheet 1 column A become empty. Else then remain the original value. This is my currently formula, but it process so slow and I have more than 10k rows. How can I modify this formula to make it run faster?

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A1;Sheet2!B:B;""));A1;A1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(A1=Sheet2!B:B))<>0,"",A1)` ?